# Function to make a sound on borders when touching Microsoft surface device (tabletop)

Tags: javascript, java, c++, windows, touchscreen

Is there any function in C++ or Java to make a sound when a blind or visually impaired user touches the borders of the screen? Or when the user touches a specific part of the screen?
The device I'm using is "Microsoft surface device" so its running on Windows 8

I'm not really good in coding.

Comment: You want the device to be able to detect if the user is blind?

Comment: @Jonathan Potter , No , he wants to alert the blind user that he is moving(cursor) toward border of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way :

Inside a loop -

- Get caret position(x,y) using [getcursorpos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648390(v=vs.85).aspx)
- Check that caret position(x,y) if it lie inside corner area (see image , here corner area = black area)

[image]

- If caret position is in corner area , create sound else do nothing.

**How to check caret position ?**
*Recently i use this function to operate mouse using gesture where i check caret position if it lies inside ROI , see image*

[image]

View this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QlLUvOuWeLE) for better understanding .